# How to save data to sqlite When There is no network and send to server once the network connection is restored in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I want to know How I can use `SQflite` to save data when there is no network and then send it to Server.

When the network is present and the user performs an action, Iwant to send it to the server. When there isn't any network, the data Which I want to send should be saved to the `SQflite DB`, then pushed it once the network is restored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connectivity](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity) package. There are also many tutorials for sqflite.